# Converting new Date() to UTC format in typescript, angular

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime-format, utc

I have a request from angular, which sends date to server.

```
const activationDate = new Date();
```

I need to convert this to UTC date format before sending the request

In my model, I have a Date variable to pass the date to server

```
export class PersonDetails {
  id: string;
  activationDate?: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
personModel: PersonDetail;    

const activationDate = new Date();

this.personModel.activationDate = new Date(activationDate.getUTCFullYear(),
                                            activationDate.getUTCMonth(),
                                            activationDate.getUTCDate(),
                                            activationDate.getUTCHours(),
                                            activationDate.getUTCMinutes(),
                                            activationDate.getUTCSeconds()
                                            );
```

OR
Can use a separate method to get UTCDate

```
const activationDate = this.getNowUTC();    

private getNowUTC() {
  const now = new Date();
  return new Date(now.getTime() + (now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
}
```

[A good article on converting DateTime](https://praveenlobo.com/blog/how-to-convert-javascript-local-date-to-utc-and-utc-to-local-date/)

Answer (score 14):

You can use `toISOString()` function ([MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)).

> The timezone is always zero UTC offset.

```
const activationDate = new Date().toISOString();
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a pipe like this

```
@Pipe({ name: 'UTCDate'})
export class UTCDatePipe implements PipeTransform  {
    constructor() {}
    transform(value) {
        if (value)  {
            return  moment.utc(value).format('YYYY MMMM DD');
        } else {
              return '';
        }
    }
}
```

And view like this:

```
{{invoice.invoiceDate | UTCDate}}
```

and to this app.module

```
import {UTCDatePipe} from "@app/utcDate.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        UTCDatePipe
    ],
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the above solutions are correct if you need to play with the date a lot you can use moment.js lib which might be really helpful.

Refer http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/ for more.

```
1. npm install moment
2. import * as _moment from 'moment';
const moment = _moment;
const utcDate = moment.utc();
console.log(utcDate.format());
```

Comment: Moment has been deprecated, [themselves recommend not to use it anymore](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Comment: This answer was posted 2 years back